# Creating dataframe from dict inside dict with new column names

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks something like:

```
dictionary = {'A' : {'a': 2,
                     'b': 3,
                     'c': 4},

              'B' : {'a': 4,
                     'd': 3,
                     'e': 3}}
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like,

```
   P1   P2   P3    
0  A    a     2  
1  A    b     3
2  A    c     4
3  B    a     4
4  B    d     3
5  B    e     3
```

I want to have the keys of first dictionary as one column and keys and values of the inner dictionary as second and third column respectively with new column names.

Comment: What is your question; your post is a list of statements. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your nested dict into a list of lists before you create the data frame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([[k, kk, vv] for k, v in dictionary.items() for kk, vv in v.items()], 
                  columns=['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])

  P1 P2  P3
0  A  a   2
1  A  b   3
2  A  c   4
3  B  a   4
4  B  d   3
5  B  e   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `from_dict`, `stack` and `sort_values`:

```
(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
            .stack()
            .reset_index()
            .set_axis(['P2','P1','P3'], axis=1, inplace=False)
            .sort_values(['P1','P2'])
            .sort_index(1))
```

Output:

```
  P1 P2   P3
0  A  a  2.0
2  A  b  3.0
3  A  c  4.0
1  B  a  4.0
4  B  d  3.0
5  B  e  3.0
```

Comment: what pandas version are you using or did you doctor your `dictionary` value at all? I get  `TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`.

Comment: @MattR Ah.. yes set_axis with inplace parameter is new 0.21.0

Comment: I am getting an error: set_axis() got multiple values for keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: @Arch set_axis with axis and inplace parameters is new 0.21.0.

Answer (score 1):

Using pd.Serise

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
Out[464]: 
  level_0 level_1    0
0       A       a  2.0
1       A       b  3.0
2       A       c  4.0
3       B       a  4.0
4       B       d  3.0
5       B       e  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to Scott's, however like we both mentioned in the comments, if you do not have version `0.21.0`+ you will receive `TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`. Below is my solution that is working on `0.20.2`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary).stack().sort_values()\ #original read and stack
.reset_index()\ #reseting the index
.sort_values(['level_1', 'level_0'])\ #sorting the values based on your needed ouput
.rename(index=str, columns={'level_0': 'P2', 'level_1' : 'P1', 0:'P3'})\ #renaming the columns
.reindex_axis(axis = 1, labels=['P1', 'P2','P3']) #putting the columns in correct order

    P1  P2  P3
0   A   a   2.0
1   A   b   3.0
5   A   c   4.0
4   B   a   4.0
2   B   d   3.0
3   B   e   3.0
```